# Gmail "Send mail as" feature still reveals original email address when viewing the email's HTML

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, alias

I have a email address for my personal domain set up as user@mydomain.com. However, I want to be able to receive and send emails using this email address through my Gmail account. I've set up email forwarding and used Gmail's "Send mail as" feature to successfully achieve this. Now when people receive emails from me, they will see "user@mydomain.com" as the sender.

However, the recipient of my email can still see my Gmail address by viewing the original HTML of the email.

I want it so that ONLY the user@mydomain.com is visible even when they view the original format of the email. I do not want my personal Gmail account being exposed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it your configuration wrong somewhere? Using Gmail I can successfully send mail showing my Yahoo mailbox as sender.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more detail to explain what you are doing. In GMail, it is possible to set up aliases such as: mymainaccount@gmail.com with an alias such as mymainaccount.specific_subname@gmail.com. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: I would suggest providing headers from some emails showing what you don't like (Gmail show original).

Comment: I have edited the question, please let me know if further clarification would help

Comment: 1. Provide more detail; 2. Send yourself an email and provide sample headers from the email that you originally sent.  3. You mention 'email forwarding' which should probably not be a part of this and should be explained.